# Am I really reviewing correctly?

Tags: discussion, review

When I reviewing the First Posts I sometimes am wondering:

- this is a question that looks okay, (it is not spam, it is nicely worded corectly and all of that)
- but to be honnest I haven't the foggiest idea where it is about. (some field of math, I have never studied)
- I cannot even make sure if the question makes any sense in this field
- nor can I check the tags (as said before , I don't understand the question)

What is the right way forward in such a situation?

1 Skip or

2 No action needed

I would choose 2 No action needed, but is this the right choice?

Or should I choose 1 Skip?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would say either is fine. From what I've seen, questions which are correctly-formatted and worded are almost always reasonable. The main purpose of the First Posts queue is to catch posts from users who don't understand how to use the system or are intentionally abusing it.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to say that even if "the question (does not) makes any sense in this field", it is a fine question.

It frustrates and annoys me when people round on someone for asking a question which does not make sense, as often this is because they don't understand the topic. That is, the OP needs help to ask a better question (that is, help to understand the topic) rather than mindless criticism! (Of course, there are exceptions.)

So to answer your question: do what Alex Becker says, but remove, or greatly weaken, "does the question make any sense?" from your check-list.