# Reviewing answers

Tags: discussion, review

Still wondering if I am reviewing correctly.

in [Am I really reviewing correctly?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13267/am-i-really-reviewing-correctly) my question was about reviewing questions.

This time it is about a first answer.

In my private opinion the quality of answer needs at least as hight as the question.

Then I was asked to review an answer for the question question: 
[Meaning of $A^A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807650/meaning-of-aa)

There was an answer (sorry I cannot find the proposed answer anywhere anymore), the problem is that I don't understand matrixces (what is I presume the the subject of the question)

There was also a comment from i guess a more knowledgable persons than myself,( I think it was https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55235/git-gud ) and he commented something like "you misunderstand the question , you are confusing this ".

(in this case the comment was probably correct)

How should I review this answer?

I decided to skip the answer.

Was my action correct?

And what if next time there is no such help of a more knowledgable person, it it the best to skip answers i don't understand or should I say "no action needed"?

Comment: If you are ever uncertain about what to do in a review, the best option is to skip.  Another user (who may be more knowledgeable about the area) will come around before long to review it.

Comment: @Arthur: I agree, and I often skip, but the system is design to award action, not admittance of lack of knowledge for action. So sometimes it's just easier to act.

Comment: @Asaf: One could consider the reward for inaction in the face of uncertainty your continued ability to peruse the review queues and use math.SE in general.  Users can be banned from reviewing, or even temporarily suspended, if they "guess wrong" too often when reviewing. (This is weakly analogous to the usual usage of the site: there are few, if any, immediate downsides to answering (action!) any question you see regardless of whether you know anything about the topic. But providing too many bad answers will result in great difficulty in using the site at all.)

Comment: @Arthur: Yeah, but how effective are the audits? I mean the last few audits I received were either obviously "good posts", and more than once spam/offensive which I personally flagged as such. If other people get these sort of audits, then the system ineffectively "punishes" those who always take action. Not to mention, often the audits are with things which have a real obvious answer, and not something which you *should* skip because it's borderline.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed some [in this related thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12633/is-it-rude-to-skip-most-edits) and [in the comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13814/reviewing-answers#comment54539_13814), skipping is very good practice and you should not be afraid of it.  In particular, I recommend you **always skip a question if (1) you aren't willing to put in the time to read it through seriously, or (2) you don't understand the math involved.**